# For Loop incrementing by 2s instead of 1

Tags: python, list, for-loop

Homework: Self teaching out of a book. Still very much a novice

I create a list then print that list out using a For-Loop.  It works fine.

```
guests=["John","Jeff","Jack","Mom"]

for i in range(len(guests)):
    print(f"I would like to invite you, {guests[i]}, to dinner.")
```

Now I recreate this same thing but am removing everyone from the list.

```
for i in range(len(guests)):
    person=guests.pop(i)
    print(f"Sorry {person}, dinner has been canceled.")
```

This is where it goes wrong.  The code increments by 2 then says pop index out of range.
If it starts at 0 and goes for the length 0,1,2,3 then why is it jumping by 2s?

Comment: Related: [Strange result when removing item from a list while iterating over it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list-while-iterating-over-it) and  [How to remove items from a list while iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating).

Comment: @jarmod I think that's the dup I was looking for.

Comment: im trying to use the pop method as to print the popped out name.  I do understand remove or even del works fine, yet it is the pop() feature I am attempting to learn. Then to understand why it is going in increments of 2 and not 1

Comment: @JohnnyMopp yes, it's quite hard to find some of the canonical questions on SO. Especially under time pressure to be the first ;-) The in-built SO search is not the best option, in my experience.

Comment: @CooperFlats pop() alters the length of the list. so len(list) = 4 list.pop(0), len(list)=3

Comment: !!  I see, how simple. thank you

Comment: solved it by not incrementing pop.  Thank you dbstringer for that nudge.  solution came to be:: for i in range(len(guests)):
    person = guests.pop(0)
    print(f"Sorry {person}, the dinner is canceled.")

Comment: If you're going to do that then you could simply do: `while guests: print(guests.pop(0))`